# Identify path of value from console results

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular project that calls an API. I'm trying to figure out how to reference a value from the returned results and am trying to figure it out by looking at the console.log results.

Here is my service call:

```
  var getUserCampaigns = function(userId){
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
      $http.get(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/campaign/user/' + userId).then(function(result){
        if(result.status !== 200) {
          reject(result);
        } else {
          resolve(result.data);
          console.log('from service: ', result);
        }
      },function(error){
        console.log('There was an error in getting user campaigns: ', error);
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  };
```

Here is what is returned by the API call:

```
Returned campaign: e
                    $$state: Object
                        status: 1
                        value: Array[2]
                            0: Object
                                __v: 0
                                _id: "583bc4f3bbb04f2b65a34ebc"
                                description: "This is my description"
                                endDate: "2016-11-28T05:47:31.261Z"
                                goalAmount: 23000
                                mainImage: "image.gif"
                                ownerId: "58352f5d2632c371aa951be7"
                                postedOn: "2016-11-28T05:47:31.261Z"
                                startDate: "2016-11-28T05:47:31.261Z"
                                subtitle: "subtitle here see"
                                title: "Title of my campaign"
```

In my controller, I try to reference the results like this:

```
getUserCampaigns:function(){
  this.campaigns = CampaignService.getUserCampaigns(self.userId);
  console.log('Value: ' + this.campaigns.title);
}
```

But the "Value" in my console log comes back as "undefined".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're burying yourself too deep into promises.  A typical pattern would be for a service to return a promise and have that promise handled in a controller.

First, the service ... understand that $http.get() is a promise and you don't need to wrap it in another.

```
app.service('CampaignService', function($http) {
  this.getUserCampaigns = function(userId) {
    return $http.get(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/campaign/user/' + userId);
  };
});
```

Then in the controller you can handle the promise returned by the service.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(CampaignService) {
  CampaignService.getUserCampaigns(self.userId).then(function(result) {
    this.campaigns = result.data;
    console.log('Value: ' + this.campaigns.title);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using $q to make async calls to the API. Your suggestion simplifies things quite a bit, but I think the default $http.(verb) is synchronous by default. Isn't that the case?

Comment: It is in this case because of the .then() but I assume you need it to be so that you can handle the response data.